# How to reduce recompositions when animating text color?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-animation, android-jetpack-compose-animation

Current code

```
@Composable
fun TextDemo() {
    var selectedIndex by remember {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }
    Row {
        TabText(
            text = "First",
            isSelected = selectedIndex == 0,
            onClick = {
                selectedIndex = 0
            },
        )
        TabText(
            text = "Second",
            isSelected = selectedIndex == 1,
            onClick = {
                selectedIndex = 1
            },
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun TabText(
    text: String,
    isSelected: Boolean,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    val tabTextColor by animateColorAsState(
        targetValue = if (isSelected) {
            Color.Red
        } else {
            Color.Black
        },
        animationSpec = tween(
            easing = LinearEasing,
        ),
        label = "tab_text_color",
    )

    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(8.dp)
            .clickable {
                onClick()
            },
        text = text,
        color = tabTextColor,
    )
}
```

UI for reference
Two `Text` in a `Row`

[image: UI Screenshot]

Layout Inspector recompositions

[image: Screenshot of Layout inspector]

**Question**

**How to reduce the recompositions when text color changes?**

For properties like `alpha`, `transition`, etc, It is possible to avoid recompositions when animating using `Modifier.graphicsLayer {}`

The same code with `alpha` animation instead of color is recomposed only once per selection change.

[image: Layout inspector screenshot]

Code

```
@Composable
fun TabText(
    text: String,
    isSelected: Boolean,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    val alphaValue by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = if (isSelected) {
            1F
        } else {
            0.5F
        },
        animationSpec = tween(
            easing = LinearEasing,
        ),
        label = "tab_text_color",
    )

    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .graphicsLayer {
                alpha = alphaValue
            }
            .padding(8.dp)
            .clickable {
                onClick()
            },
        text = text,
    )
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all when you log recomposition that reads a State it should better be done inside `SideEffect` otherwise it's possible to get false positives, because logging itself also counts as a State `read`.

To have one recomposition for text color change you can use `Canvas` or any draw Modifier inside `Tab` and call only draw phase while `Color` changes using `TextMeasurer` and `drawText` function of `DrawScope`.

Second option is to use BlendModes with Modifier.drawContent{} to change color  with one recompostion as

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun TextAnimationTest() {

    var isSelected by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    SideEffect {
        println("Recomposing...")
    }

    val tabTextColor by animateColorAsState(
        targetValue = if (isSelected) {
            Color.Red
        } else {
            Color.Black
        },
        animationSpec = tween(
            easing = LinearEasing,
        ),
        label = "tab_text_color",
    )


  Column {
      Button(
          onClick = {
              isSelected = isSelected.not()
          }
      ) {
          Text("Selected: $isSelected")
      }

      Text("Some Text", modifier = Modifier
          .graphicsLayer {
              compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen
          }
          .drawWithContent {
              drawContent()

              drawRect(
                  color = tabTextColor,
                  blendMode = BlendMode.SrcIn
              )
          }
      )
  }
}
```

Comment:  So complicated solution for such a simple use-case. 

Comment: All you have to do is set graphicsLayer for blend mode and draw a rectangle above text with a `BlendMode.SrcIn`. Other option is drawing inside Canvas. But bottomline is you need to do it in draw phase if you don't want to trigger recompositions

Comment: Also found that `BasicText` has a lambda modifier for this use-case. Material `Text` does not use lambda. https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1688616899479009?thread_ts=1688614320.086279&cid=CJLTWPH7S

Comment: That's great then. Lambdas are the way to defer state reads from composition to layout or draw phases. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/bestpractices#defer-reads

Comment: Raised an issue for the color provider in `Text`. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/305542850

Comment: @Abhimanyu that's great. It would be nice feature to have.

Answer (score 1):

Given I am able to replace my `Text` usage with `BasicText` for my use-case, I can use the `ColorProvider` provided by `BasicText`.

[Source](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1688616899479009?thread_ts=1688614320.086279&cid=CJLTWPH7S).

---

This may not be possible in all scenarios and for such use cases, [this solution by Thracian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77297119/9636037) can be used.

---

Created an issue to provide support for color provider in `Text` as well.  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/305542850